# Typescript - change DOM element inner HTML?

Tags: angularjs, dom, typescript

I've been searching around this afternoon trying to figure out how to use Typescript to change the html of a span element in my breadcrumb trail, OR get an angular statement to evaluate/compile in a jQuery selector. The closest I've found is to use $compile, but I'm not sure if this will work since I don't have the data until after my resolve completes? If it will, I'll need a hand understanding where to inject $compile into the app.

**index.module.ts**

```
angular.module('pccrm', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngResource',
            'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'feature-flags', 'trNgGrid', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'toastr', 'cgBusy',
            'fixtable', 'angularUtils.directives.uiBreadcrumbs', 'LocalStorageModule'])
...
```

**index.route.ts**

```
...
.state(Constants.SEARCH_CONTACTS_CONTACTPROFILE, {
            url: '/orgs/:externalOrgId/contacts/:profileId',
            data: {
                displayName: 'Contact Profile'
            },
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contact-profile.tmpl.html',
                    controller: 'ContactsProfileController',
                    controllerAs: 'cpc',
                    resolve: {
                        contactProfile: function (contactProfileService: IContactProfileService, $stateParams: any) {
                            return contactProfileService.getContactProfile(<string>$stateParams.externalOrgId, <string>$stateParams.profileId)
                                .then(function (contactModel: IContact) {
                                    return contactModel;
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
...
```

**contact-profile.tmpl.html**

```
...
<div class="info-group">
                    <div class="profileImage default">

                    </div>
                    <h4 class="contact-name">{{ cpc.contactProfile.fullName() }}</h4>
                    {{ cpc.contactProfile.title }}<br/>
                    <a ui-sref="search.organizations.orgProfile({externalOrgId: cpc.contactProfile.externalOrganizationId })" ng-if="cpc.contactProfile.externalOrganizationId">
                        {{ cpc.contactProfile.externalOrganizationName }}
                    </a>
                </div>
...
```

Is something like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.breadcrumb li.active span').html(
            $compile("{{ cpc.contactProfile.fullName() }}")(scope));
</script>
```

on the end of the template html the best way to do this? Or can my profile service edit the DOM somehow once it retrieves the contact info?

**NOTE** We're using angular-util-sui-breadcrumbs to generate the BCT...which currently doesnt support interpolating the resolve into the BCT with the way we have our nested named views. This is why I need to be able to modify the BCT dom after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

> Or can my profile service edit the DOM somehow once it retrieves the contact info

Yes. Export the stuff on the *scope* and use that `{{somethingOnScope.contactProfile.fullName()}}` in the UI.

More on scope : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

## Update

> You may have misread my question

No. I am saying that don't do:

```
$('.breadcrumb li.active span').html(
            $compile("{{ cpc.contactProfile.fullName() }}")(scope));
```

Instead your html should look like:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
   <li class="active">
       <span>{{somethingOnScope.contactProfile.fullName()}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And then you don't need jquery

Comment: You may have misread my question. You can see in my contact-profile html that I'm already getting values into my html. What I'm having issues with is getting an angular value into a jquery selector. Or otherwise, modify the dom inside the typescript controller or service.

Comment: @NikZ please see update. I don't think I've misread your question.

Comment: I see where you're going. I should've mentioned in the OP that the breadcrumb is being generated by the angular-utils-ui-breadcrumbs module. It doesnt support interpolation in the index.route with the way we have our nested named views setup. So until they fix that, I have to find another way to make the BCT that it generates display the dynamic text I need.

Comment: `The closest I've found is to use $compile, but I'm not sure if this will work since I don't have the data until after my resolve completes?` Unless you use data binding the best bet is to `$watch`(which might be the answer you are looking for) and then run the `$compile` (which is what you are already doing)

Comment: Ok, but to use $compile, it has to be injected into my app...correct? If so, given my index.module snippet...do I just add '$compile' after 'LocalStorageModule'?

Comment: @NikZ that might work. But if it doesn't just get a hold of `$injector` (check the docs, you app only has a single $injector) and get it from `$injector.$get('$compile')`